# MPG videos scrambled in VLC

Tags: video, vlc

Trying to play MPG videos with VLC would only produce a black/scrambled picture. Since I couldn't find the solution anywhere on the web, I'm leaving it here as it may be useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Simply changing `Hardware decoding` from `VDPAU video decoder` to `VA-API video decoder via X11` in `Input / Codecs > Video Codec > FFmpeg` solves the problem.