# vlc playing scrambled videos

Tags: 20.04, vlc

[image: 1]

This is happening the whole time on my PC with Ubuntu. Is there a way to fix this?

I changed the codecs based on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793535/mpg-videos-scrambled-in-vlc) too, but nothing returned as the result

**UPDATE: Aug 11**

This is the result of the command: `inxi -G`

```
Graphics:
Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
Device-2: NVIDIA GM107 [GeForce 940MX] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: nouveau 
resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1366x768~60Hz 
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6
```

Comment: change the subject line as you scrambled 'playing'

Comment: The linked answer is only correct if you are running Xorg, not wayland. It would help to see your graphic system with '`inxi -G`. Copy the output and paste it into your question and **not** into the comments

Comment: @kanehekili Thanks for your help and edit. The question has been updated with the command's result.

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy to answer your question, since you have two graphics cards, and you did not elaborate where you connected your monitors to: the intel card or the nvidia card?

**Intel**

VLC usually works with the `X11 Video output (XCB)` setting, but the `XVideoOutput (XCB)`might work as well.

**Nvidia**

If you install the the additional nvidia driver (which I would recommend) the `VDPAU`usually works

When using nouveau (the default free nvidia driver) you might have luck with one if the X11 settings.

With `Tools>Preferences->Video` on `Simple Preferences` you should be able to figure out the best setting for you (since automatic obviously doesn't work)

[[image: 1]]